How can I calculate the bandwidth I will need for a video-streaming server?
I found on internet how to calculate how much bandwidth a server consumes to serve X users by streaming the videos.
I found a simple formula and I took YouTube video quality bit-rate values to measure the bandwidth:
Users to one server * Bit rate for the desired quality * Access time
For example: I want to measure the bandwidth I'll need for 100 users for streaming a video at 360p (YouTube video quality) in 1 hour. So,
100 * 750 Kbit/s * 3600 seconds = 135000000 Kbit = 135000 Mbit = 1350 Gbit
I found that some hosting providers measures the bandwidth in TB (Terabytes/month) so I took the previous value: 1350 Gbit, then I converted to GB by dividing 8 bit: 16 GBytes. If a provider says their bandwidth is 4 TB, then would I have plenty one to serve more users? Is it correct?
I know that this formula simplifies several factors but is it the correct ( and simple ) way to calculate the estimated bandwidth? Is the example calculation correct? Please, provide me better details to understand how I can measure the bandwidth.

Your initial calculation was slightly off due to an error in conversion.
For 100 users streaming at 360p for one hour, you would consume approximately 33.75 GB.
If your provider offers 4 TB/month, you will indeed have enough bandwidth. However, it's essential to account for higher figures.
Consider peak usage, potential growth, and variability in streaming quality.
The error was here: 100 users * 750 Kbit/s * 3600 seconds = **270000000** Kbit.
Conversion to megabits: 270,000,000 Kbit / 1,000 = 270,000 Mbit.
Conversion to gigabits: 270,000 Mbit / 1,000 = 270 Gbit.
Conversion to gigabytes: 270 Gbit / 8 (since there are 8 bits in a byte) = 33.75 GBytes.
Bandwidth check per month: Now, to determine if 4 TB is sufficient for the month, you need to convert the gigabytes to terabytes: 33.75 GB for 1 hour.
If the video is streamed for 1 hour daily, the total traffic would be: 33.75 GB * 30 days = 1012.5 GB (≈1 TB per month).
I hope I've helped you with your answer.

Thank you Evgeny. You're right at the initial calculation, I used 50 users.

All good, man, it happens to everyone)
